# When is a wife categorized as a moredet?

Tags: halacha-theory, marriage, women

I understand there are two main reasons that a wife would be [categorized as a moredet](https://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/14066)

1. She refused to be intimate with her husband to cause him distress
2. She refuses to be intimate with her husband because he disgusts her

I would like to know the following

1. Does the wife attain the status of moredet only if one of the above two facts is established in Beit Din? Meaning if she told her husband, or others the reason for the lack of intimacy privately, but then refused or was unable to communicate this fact in court would she still be a moredet?
2. If the wife refused to be intimate with her husband for any other reason besides the two mentioned above would she be considered a moredet?
3. Does the wife need to be warned of potentially becoming a moredet or would she become one as soon as she refuses to be intimate with her husband for the above reasons?

Comment: Factual disputes about mored[et] aren't justicable https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8_%D7%A2%D7%96_%D7%93

Comment: Not sure about your second question. According to the gemoro she loses a bit of her kesuba every week she is. Isnt that the same as a warning.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3QzUzVlpK1M&ab_channel=AnneTanenbaumCentreforJewishStudies